# Webmaster tools reporting crawl errors that don't seem to exist?

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-search-console

Google Webmaster Tools is giving me loads of crawl Errors of a certain type but I just can't see where its getting it from

Its reporting that the error is a 404 on this page (which definitely doesn't exist)

```
http://www.soundshelter.net/artist/www.soundshelter.net/artist/Arnold+Jarvis
```

and its being linked to from this page

```
http://www.soundshelter.net/artist/Arnold+Jarvis
```

There is no link to the first page anywhere on that second page. I am getting the same error for so many of the pages on my site (all dynamically created)

Any ideas why this is happening? Could it be something to do with the way I'm creating links in the code?

```
<a href="/artist/Arnold Jarvis">Arnold Jarvis</a>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay Franco the problem is in your canonical code in your website thats create all the 404 errors.

For example take this page
http://www.soundshelter.net/artist/Arnold+Jarvis
on line 33 you will see this line

```
            <link rel="canonical" href="www.soundshelter.net/artist/Arnold+Jarvis" />
```

This line create the 404 page across all of your CMS system its probably some of the system addons if you will add there **http://** all of your 404 pages will be fixed:)